# Hibernate not able to enter foreign key value in table

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

Below is the scenario i m trying to implement in my code but not able to proceed further.I  an stuck from past 3 days due to this problem

Table A,B,C
Table A {
colmnn PKA
Column Test;

```
@OneToMany
@Cascade( { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
@JoinColumn(name = "PKA")
private Collection<TableC> tablec= new ArrayList<TableC>();
```

}

Table B{
column PKB
column test2;
  
`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tablec",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade( { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL,org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    private List tableC= new ArrayList(); //List is used only for Hibernate mapping`

}

Table c{
column PKC

@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PKA" )
    private TableA tableA;

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PKB",nullable = false,unique=true)
private TableB tableb;
```

}

So Table C has many to one relationship with Table A and
one to one relationship with table B(which is achieve by unique is "true")

Now my problem is when i am inserting data 
Hibernate first insert table B data after that it is trying to insert table c data and throw error cannot insert Null in not null column.
If i make PkA in table C as not null it is inserting all data properly .IN hibernate logs it is firing sql statement in below order
Table B Table C Table A.  Table C insert query should be executed in last .
any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each kind of association is described in the hibernate documentation, with examples. You should read the documentation.

Anyway, here are the problems your mapping has.

If you have a one-to-one association between B and C, the annotations to use are `@OneToOne` and `@OneToOne`. Not `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`. And of course, you should have a field of type `TableC` in `TableB` instead of a field of type `List<TableC>`.

When you have a bidirectional OneToOne or OneToMany association, the side which contains the foreign key in its table must be the owner side. The other side must be the inserse side. On the inverse side, there must be a `mappedBy` attribute, and no `JoinColumn` annotation. So, in TableA, the association with TableC should be defined like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tableA")
@Cascade( { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
private Collection<TableC> tablec= new ArrayList<TableC>();
```

Comment: Thanx JB for Valuable comments.

Comment: Thanx JB for Valuable comments.  In my case side contains foreign key is not owner table. but i achieve solution using following way  i removed entry of table c from table B.  and also as per u r suggestion i changed my inverse side to mappedby instead of joincolumn(As it gives problem during cascade delete).Now i can do all possible operation peacefully.Thanx a ton mate.